# Is it possible to switch the dividend and the divisor of MongoDB's $mod query operator?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB's [$mod query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/) provides a way to select documents where the value *V* of a field divided by a divisor *D* has the specified remainder *R*. So it selects documents where *V mod D* equals *R*.

I need to switch the dividend and the divisor of the modulo operation. In other words, I need to select documents where a provided dividend *D* divided by the value *V* of a field has the specified remainder *R*. So I need to select documents where *D mod V* equals *R*.

Is it possible to switch the dividend and the divisor of MongoDB's $mod query operator? If not, is it possible to pass the query a custom function which would take care of this?

Answer (score 0):

A regular [`.find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query with the [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/) operator will not work here, but still, you can do this using the aggregation framework and the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator and the [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) arithmetic aggregation operator.

Suppose we have the following documents in our collection:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573f624b4c01ce47a183a632"), "a" : 4 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573f63494c01ce47a183a634"), "a" : 12 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573f63504c01ce47a183a635"), "a" : 6 },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573f63504c01ce47a183a636"), "a" : 24 }
```

The following query return all those documents where `60` modulo the value of the field `a` equals `0`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$eq": [ {"$mod": [ 60, "$a" ] }, 0 ] }, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```

which produces:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573f624b4c01ce47a183a632"), "a" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573f63494c01ce47a183a634"), "a" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("573f63504c01ce47a183a635"), "a" : 6 }
```

Another probably less efficient way to do it, is to use the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator.

```js
db.collection.find("60 % this.a === 0")
```